# Maximum json file size which can be decoded without failure

Tags: php, json, decoding

I have a php array structure

```
Array
(
    [car] => Array
        (
            [red] => 0.333
            [orange] => 0.333
            [blue] => 0.333
        )

    [truck] => Array
        (
            [white] => 0.333
            [green] => 0.333
            [blue] => 0.333
        )
)
```

I have been using serialize to save the array to a text file, and unserialize to get back the array form.  Unfortunately, the serialized array is getting very large, but mostly due to the float point (bug or by design) conversion when serialized.  For example, instead of 0.333, the serialized process converts .333 into .3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333.  This made me want to switch to json_encode to save the array.  When compare serialize to json_encode, the serialized file is 40MB in size vs 8MB size for json_encode.

That is great, except when I try to json_decode the file, it is no longer in the array form.  I tried json_decode($array, true), but that does not work either.

How can I get json_encode to work for this example?

PS, my floating point number was generated by rounding off the decimals.  Another answer that I found on Stack Overflow suggested that instead of using `round($part/$sum, 3);`, use `sprintf('%.3f', $part/$sum);` which turned the floating point into a string.  That alone cut the serialized file down from 40MB to 19MB, but it still much larger than the json_encode file size of 8MB.

Comment: When you decode the json_encoded data, what _do_ you get?

Comment: Working from your array here, this [phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/eit-4nm) successfully encodes and decodes to array format.

Comment: Thanks Mike W, your answers helped me figured out that json_decode does not work well with large file.  The largest json file that I was able to json_decode is only about .5-.6MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'problem' is due to json_decode inability to read large json_encode files.  The largest json file that can work is only ~.5MB.  Tested on 4GB Ram, 4 core Xeon server, and also 4gb localhost laptop. I also had set memory_limit in the php.ini file to be 3GB for other php routines (yes, 3GB) and restarted apache.  So the memory_limit setting appears not to be the problem.

Error message was not helpful, it stated that

Warning:  array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/xxxxx/public_html/xxxx.php on line xx

Hopefully this error message would help some person in the future to narrow down the bug.

Comment: Your maximum file size seems rather small as a limit. Your error message implies that your decode returned a `null`, which will happen if the decode fails for some reason, The error can be determined by calling [json_last_error_msg()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php). There are a number of possible errors that might have arisen, some of which could possibly be addressed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I found others who have said that they have problems with json decode's handling of large arrays too, and there are classes to get around the problem.  I thought that .6MB was a little small to run into this problem too, but then there is no definitive comparison of how large the array has to be before json decode fails.  But it probably has to do with the size and complexity of the array.  As it turned out, the more data my array has, the less useful it is to my algorithm, had to revert back to smaller array.